# Flow duration curve - title with the name of a data frame in a list

Tags: r, list, plot, time

I want to create a flow duration curve (FDC) for the daily streamflow at each station. This daily streamflow for each station is saved as a zoo object in a list. When I plot the FDC for each station, I want to put in the title the name of the data frame in the list that corresponds to the extension name.

This is the structure of my list

```
> str(listDF_zoo)
List of 2
 $ 094985005:‘zoo’ series from 2007-10-31 to 2020-09-29
  Data: Named num [1:4718] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.01 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4718] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  Index:  Date[1:4718], format: "2007-10-31" "2007-11-01" "2007-11-02" "2007-11-03" ...
 $ 09498501 :‘zoo’ series from 1995-10-01 to 2020-09-29
  Data: Named num [1:9131] 0.14 0.08 0.08 0.07 0.07 0.06 0.07 0.07 0.07 0.07 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:9131] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  Index:  Date[1:9131], format: "1995-10-01" "1995-10-02" "1995-10-03" "1995-10-04" ...
```

and this is the code I am using:

```
FDC <- lapply(listDF_zoo,function(x){fdc(x, main=names(x))})
```

The part of `main=names(x)` is not working and that it is the one I am looking to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lapply`, unfortunately, isn't able to access the names of list it's using. One common work-around is to use the index instead, e.g.,

```
lapply(seq_along(listDF_zoo),
       function(i) fdc(listDF_zoo[[i]], main = names(listDF_zoo)[i])
)
```

Comment: or iterate over the names: `lapply(names(listDF_zoo), function(nm) fdc(listDF_zoo[[nm]], main = nm)` or use `mapply(function(x, nm) fdc(x, main = nm), listDF_zoo, names(listDF_zoo))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `purrr`'s `imap` which has access to both data and name :

```
FDC <- purrr::imap(listDF_zoo, ~fdc(.x, main=.y))
```

Comment: Nice find - hopefully something like this will make it into the `imap` documentation...

Answer (score 0):

An option with `Map` from `base R`

```
Map(fdc, listDF_zoo, main = names(listDF_zoo))
```